# How to patch an function which intermittently raises exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I am calling a function from a third party library, which intermittently fails. For an realistic integration test, I need to patch this function with something which intermittently fails. As a happy path test when nothing fails, the following patch works:

```
with patch('ThirdPartyLib.get_something') as mock_get_something:
    mock_get_something.side_effect = iter(((None, 1), (None, 2),
                                          (None, 3), (None, 4),))
```

I need to do something like the following, expecting to get the same results as in the previous case:

```
with patch('ThirdPartyLib.get_something') as mock_get_something:
    mock_get_something.side_effect = iter(((None, 1), (None, 2),
                    MockThirdPartyLibException(),
                                          (None, 3), (None, 4),))
```

Unfortunately, after MockThirdPartyLibException has been raised, subsequent calls to side_effect result in StopIteration.

To get around the problem, I created this class:

```
class MockThirdParty:
    def __init__(self):
        self.call_count = 0

    def get_something(self, ignored_param):
        self.call_count += 1
        if self.call_count == 3:
            raise MockThirdPartyLibException()
        yield (None, self.call_count)
```

I used this class as follows:

```
test_getter = MockThirdParty()
with patch('ThirdPartyLib.get_something') as mock_get_something:
    mock_get_something.side_effect = test_getter.get_something
```

This did not work out: test_getter.get_something never got invoked. Instead of tuples [(None, 1), (None, 2), and so on, I am getting this:

```
[<generator object get_something at
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

If I replace yield with return in my function, the first call blows up:

```
class MockThirdParty:
    def __init__(self):
        self.call_count = 0

    def get_something(self, ignored_param):
        self.call_count += 1
        if self.call_count == 3:
            raise MockThirdPartyLibException()
        #yield (None, self.call_count)
        return (None, self.call_count)

result = next(effect)
StopIteration
```

Comment: Does it work if you return rather than yield in `get_something`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman nope - I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original attempt *should* work with `side_effect`:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m.side_effect = [1, ValueError(), 3]
>>> m()
1
>>> m()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError
>>> m()
3
>>> m()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
StopIteration
>>>
```

Can you post a bit more code from your tests - specifically how your test is actually using `ThirdPartyLib.get_something`?

On a side note, there's no need for you to wrap the side_effect tuple in `iter()`, since the tuple itself is already iterable.

Comment: You were right - some other thing was raising StopIteration.